# take the stage "to" the chorus

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.buzzfeed.com/rubycramer/turning-to-the-general-clinton-makes-pitch-to-the-thoughtful?utm_term=.ykbJa5xp8#.pmaPRNzkJ

I saw this sentence in a piece of news "“We will unify our party to win this election and build an America where we can all rise together,” Clinton said after **taking the stage to the chorus** of Survivor’s “Eye of the Tiger,” a departure from campaign’s strict song list, underscoring the occasion."

I kinda understand what it means, by could anyone explain a little bit more about why "to" is used here (to the chorus) ?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you march to the beat of a different drummer?  "Marching to the beat" and "taking the stage to the chorus" are equivalent structures, syntactically.

Comment: You may be parsing it improperly: it’s [take the stage] [to the chorus of]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to the rhythms of the song mentioned.

Much like dancing to but with a slightly advanced take on the predicate as a prefix.